# Seek() error in python flask and pyrebase

Tags: python, api, flask, jpeg

I am newbie in python and flask API development.
I have created an API which accept image through html post form after the uploaded image I am passing that image to pillow library to resize but when I use .put() method to store the image to pyrebase receive an seek() error
My code:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from file import ImgId
import pyrebase
import io



config={
"apiKey": "AIzaSyBvlJpkV7rcYwbx3wNEBARKvrpHMBALXuw",
    "authDomain": "allinonetools.firebaseapp.com",
   "databaseURL": "https://allinonetools-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    "projectId": "allinonetools",
   "storageBucket": "allinonetools.appspot.com",
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

app = Flask(__name__)


storage=firebase.storage()


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
    

@app.route("/size", methods=["POST"])
def process_image():
    file = request.files['image']
    # Read the image via file.stream
    img = Image.open(file.stream)
    new_image = img.resize((400, 400))
    img_url=ImgId()
    storage.child(img_url).put(img)
    

    return jsonify({'msg': 'success', 'size': [new_image.width, new_image.height]})
   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
This is the error
```

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrirC.png)

Comment: Can you put a picture with the rest of the error, it seems that some info is cut off from the picture

Comment: Also it seems that put() needs a user token or admin account and you dont have either of them in your code. Try to either make yourself an admin or add a user token to your put()